# Unity3D: как обратиться к gameobjects, которые содержатся в <List>

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть элемент  который служит для хранения gameobject'ов , мне нужно обратиться ко всем этим gameobject'ам для дальнейшей работы сразу со всеми ими.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос слишком размыт. Трудно понять, что у вас за ситуация и что вам нужно. Если исходить из текущего описания, то вам нужно использовать банальный цикл для перебор элементов списка. Например:

```
for (int i =0; i < objList.Count; i++)
{
    var obj = objList[i];
    //Делаете что-то с вашим объектом (obj)
}
```